# Issue with IsInstance function and request.Session

Tags: python, python-requests, spotipy

For my current project, I'm using the Spotipy python library and using it to create an instance that I can use to access the Spotify API. All works fine, however, once the code reaches the end of its run I get this error

```
Exception ignored in: <function Spotify.__del__ at 0x0000021B06FEFDC0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\greys\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spotipy\client.py", line 215, in __del__
TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types
```

This prompted me to look into the client library and find out that the destructor code is as follows

```
def __del__(self):
        """Make sure the connection (pool) gets closed"""
        if isinstance(self._session, requests.Session):
            self._session.close()
```

I added a line temporarily to check the type of self._session and the type is listed as <class 'requests.sessions.Session'>, so I'm assuming the issue is with the use of requests.Session as argument two. Would anyone have any insight as to what the issue is/how to remedy this? It doesn't stop the code from running, but it's just a nuisance to see at the end of every run. Attached is my script for reference

```
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials
import json
import os
import configparser
import csv
from google.cloud import storage
from time import perf_counter
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import requests

parser = configparser.ConfigParser()
parser.read("pipeline.conf")
client_id = parser.get("spotify_credentials", "client_id")
client_secret = parser.get("spotify_credentials", "client_secret")
sp = SpotifyClientCredentials(client_id=client_id, client_secret=client_secret)
access_token = sp.get_access_token(as_dict=False)
sp = spotipy.client.Spotify(auth = access_token)
print('Made Spotipy Client')
```

I tried altering the destructor code to remove the if statement, which worked, but I'd like to see if there's potential user error on my end that is causing this. I also ran the same code in a Jupyter notebook and had no issues with the destructor

Comment: What does `type(requests.Session)` give? This may be a dependency version mismatch, where `Session` is no long a type (it could be a "constructor function" or something now, or was such a function and the library is outdated).